# Ruby on Rails JSON to Model Conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

```
 def create
      @match_data = JSON.parse(request.raw_post)

      @match = @match_data["match"]

      match = Match.new
      match.match_length = @match["match_length"]
      match.quest = @match["quest"]
      match.humans_team_stats = @match["humans_team_stats"]
      match.supernaturals_team_stats = @match["supernaturals_team_stats"]
      @match_data["users_match_stats"].each do |user|
        user_account = User.find user["id"]
        match.users << user_account
        match.save!

        user_match_stats = UserMatchStat.new
        user_match_stats.user = user_account
        user_match_stats.match = match
        user_match_stats.kills = user["kills"]
        user_match_stats.deaths = user["deaths"]
        user_match_stats.assists = user["assists"]
        user_match_stats.damage_dealt = user["damage_dealt"]
        user_match_stats.damage_taken = user["damage_taken"]
        user_match_stats.first_blood = user["first_blood"]

        user_match_stats.save!

        match.user_match_stats << user_match_stats

      end

      render json: @match_data
    end
```

is this literally the best way to map an incoming json object to a rails model and make a record for it? There's gotta be a better way than this...

Answer (score 1):

Provided your model's columns are the same as the keys in the JSON object (which it looks like they are from your code snippet), you can use `symbolize_keys` to turn the json objects into a ruby hash that your rails model will accept as commit params.  It could look something like the following:

```
match = Match.create(match_length: @match["match_length"], quest: @match["quest"], humans_team_stats: @match["humans_team_stats"], supernaturals_team_stats: @match["supernaturals_team_stats"])

@match_data["users_match_stats"].each do |user|
        user_account = User.find user["id"]
        match.users << user_account
        UserMatchStat.create(user.symbolize_keys)
end
```

Comment: Hey what are your thoughts on this idea. Instead of storing my user match stats in a separate table, and then having a join table for it. What do you think about just storing the match stats as a single json column? For example, when passing my request, I would store the main match information, but then just plop the rest into a single json column? What are the pros and cons of doing this?

Comment: If you are using `ActiveModel::Assignment` (which is used by `ActiveModel::Model` and `ActiveRecord::Base`) it does not matter if the input has string or symbol keys since they are used to call the setter method.

Comment: The cons of storing it in a JSON column is that you get none of the benefits of using a schema to strongly type your data or the benefits of having a seperate model to encapsulate the logic and ActiveRecord relations. You  just have an untyped mess thats a PITA to query.

Comment: The pro is that a JSON column can be used to store irregular data that does not have a fixed schema and can store raw JSON responses.